# Read text file using FileReader in (Angular)TypeScript

Tags: javascript, filereader

Trying to read simple text files but it does not seem to read it. When I select an image it works but when I select a text file or word doc it tells me: `sanitizing unsafe URL value`

This is the code I'm using:

```
onFilePicked(event: Event) {
    const filePicked = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
    this.form.patchValue({ file: filePicked });
    this.form.get('file').updateValueAndValidity();
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => {
      this.filePreview = reader.result;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(filePicked);
  }
```

This is the HTML code

```
<div>
     <button class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm" type="button" 
     (click)="filePicker.click()">Pick File</button>
     <input type="file" #filePicker (change)="onFilePicked($event)">
     </div>

     <div class="file-preview" *ngIf="filePreview !== '' && filePreview && 
     form.get('file').valid">
      <img [src]="filePreview" [alt]="form.value.title">
</div>
```

Does anyone spot the error, I have been reading other posts but they use jQuery. Any ideas to solve this error are welcome, thanks!

Comment: If you have nothing to contribute apart from negativity, why contribute at all? I'm sorry that I'm not as intellectual as you. @JonasLochmann

Comment: Thank you for your help, that seemed to do the trick plus changing it to, `reader.readAsText(filePicked);` from readAsUrl. I'm only new to all this and I'm trying to learn daily, will be careful next time with tags. @JonasLochmann

Answer (score 1):

For word documents or text instead of having `reader.readAsUrl(filePicked);`
Changed to `reader.readAsText(filePicked);`. 
Also when displaying the information a small mistake was having the `<img>` tag instead of a normal div tag.